# Не получается корректно заменить обычную HTTP-аутентификация, на обычную форму

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, php7

Есть код php:

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
if ($_SESSION["auth"] == 1 && (isset($_POST['user_close']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))) {
    $_SESSION["auth"] = 0;
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Admin Page"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit();
} else {
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = \DB::real_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $query = "SELECT user.log,
                 user.pass,
                 user.id AS id,
                 user.ip,
                 user_info.foto,
                 user_info.status,
                 user_info.f,
                 user_info.i,
                 user_info.o,

                 user_privelegii.pravo
          FROM `user`
          LEFT JOIN `user_info` ON `user`.`id` = `user_info`.`id`
          LEFT JOIN `user_privelegii` ON `user`.`id` = `user_privelegii`.`id`
          WHERE `log`='" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "'";
    $lst = \DB::query($query);
    $user = $lst->fetch_array();
    $partID = $user['partID'];



    if (!$user['status'] || md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) != $user['pass']) {
        Header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Admin Page"');
        Header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        exit();
    }


    $_SESSION['auth'] = 1; //........Остальной код, когда авторизация прошла...
```

как эту всю конструкцию заменить на простую форму?

Вставлял обычную форму, через $_POST передавал значение, вроде бы и работало, но как только возвращался на индексную страницу, все сбивалось и опять на форму выскакивало, видимо где-то был невнимателен.

Comment: Напишите как вы передаёте данные в этот код. Ваш <form>
Немного не понятно что значит "обычная форма"

Comment: @Илюшка сейчас все передаётся через HTTP-аутентификацию(логин и пароль), мне нужна обычная форма что-то вроде этого:
`<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин">

<input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль">

<button type="submit" name="sub" class="cd-reques-btn">ВОЙТИ В АККАУНТ</button>

</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Тогда вместо

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

используйте

```
$_POST['login'], $_POST['pass'] и т.д.
```

Вот эту строку

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = \DB::real_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
```

замените на

```
$login = \DB::real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$pass = \DB::real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
и т.д.
```

вот тут
    WHERE `log`='" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "'";
нужно менять по обстоятельствам в зависимости что в базе

а также исправить проверку md5 пароля по данным из $_POST

Comment: `WHERE log='" . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "'"` - log, это логин, он сначала я так понял проверяет есть ли такой логин, а потом начинает проверять если с таким логином совпадения пароля. К сожалению то что скинули не подходит, все работает и логинится, но как только перехожу на главную страницу, или обновляю, то снова переходит на форму

Comment: вот код http://prntscr.com/qmmb42